# Facebook-messenger-bot is not approved from review

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

I have submitted my bot for review, `page_messaging` is approved by Facebook but `page_messaging_subscriptions` is not approved so now I want to remove the `page_messaging_subscription` and again submit it for the review so Please help me how to do it! See the image below it has no X Option

[image]

Comment: Did you add another new permission? If not, why do you want to submit again (if you already have page_messaging approved)?

Comment: @CBroe Yes i have added new permission but it was not approved that's why my bot is also not going public so i want to remove that permission which is not approved

Comment: In the list of items on the App Review tab, there should be an X next to each single item to remove it.

Comment: @lukkea,@CBroe see the attached link

Comment: Contact Facebook for help, not here.

Comment: @Raptor Yes i contacted them but response is not so helping so I am going to delete that app and start from scratch again!